# Scrolling GridView's items make GridView scrolls up down and will be gone

Tags: android, android-view, android-gridview

I request you just see this video you will know what is the issue

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsZSMRPEZSI&feature=youtu.be

**Gridview scrolls and Gone when I scroll it's item**

### **This issue is not occurring when there is limited no. of items in GridView or when we scroll slowly**

I have taken Custom GridView, in that I am loading images and text from server

below is the code

GridView's XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/edtTxtProfileQuotes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/small_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_notification_shape"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/blue_notification_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/small_margin"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/light_violet" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/teambg" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grdGrupOfUnite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_below="@id/edtTxtProfileQuotes"
        android:numColumns="3" >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Adapter's xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.example.achessapp.widget.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivUniteGrpMemIcon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ivUniteGrpMemIcon"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/extra_small_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/small_margin"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

in Activity File

```
adapter = new BondMemberAdapter(mActivity, list_members_bean);
        mGridMembers.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In Adapter file

```
 public class BondMemberAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        LayoutInflater mInflator;
        Activity mActivity;
        private ArrayList<MembersBean> list_members_bean;
        Typeface tf = null;

        public BondMemberAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<MembersBean> list) {
            mActivity = activity;
            mInflator = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity);
            list_members_bean = list;
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                    mActivity.getAssets(), Constants.FONT_TYPE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list_members_bean.size();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;

            MembersBean bean = list_members_bean.get(position);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.unite_grup_member_item,
                        null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.ivUser = (CircularImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.ivUniteGrpMemIcon);
                viewHolder.tvName = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvName);
                viewHolder.tvName.setTypeface(tf);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            String text = "";

            text = bean.getScreen_name();

            //viewHolder.ivUser.setImageResource(R.drawable.unite_item);
            if (bean.getThumbnail_url() != null) {
                if (bean.getThumbnail_url().equals("null")) {
                    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(
                            "drawable://" + R.drawable.profile_placeholder,
                            viewHolder.ivUser);
                } else {
                    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(bean.getThumbnail_url(),
                            viewHolder.ivUser);
                }
            }

            else {

                ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(
                        "drawable://" + R.drawable.profile_placeholder,
                        viewHolder.ivUser);
            }
            viewHolder.tvName.setText(text);
            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            CircularImageView ivUser;
            TextView tvName;
            int position;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list_members_bean.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

    }
```